# JPA EntityManager Nullpointer Exception when splitting functionality in multiple classes (Glassfish, EclipseLink)

Tags: rest, jpa, glassfish, nullpointerexception, eclipselink

i know there are masses of questions concerning a similar problem, but i didn't manage to extract a solution for my problem.

I'm trying to build a RESTful webapplication that serves data, which is provided using JPA (EclipseLink 2.4) and runs on Glassfish 3.1.2.2.

For testing i set up a guestbook database in mysql and created this all-in-one solution:

```
// imports etc...
// Guestbook class has @Entity

@Stateless
@Path("guestbook")
public class GuestService {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @GET
    public Response entry() {
        Guestbook entry = em.find(Guestbook.class, someid);
        return Response.ok(entry.getMsg()).build();
    }
}
```

This works perfectly well, but i want to split it in to several layers like so: REST -> DAO -> Entity
Which would transform to:

```
@Stateless
@Path("guestbook")
public class GuestService {

    private DAO dao;

    @GET
    public Response entry() {
        Guestbook entry = dao.getEntry(someid);
        return Response.ok(entry.getMsg()).build();
    }
}

// ...

public class DAO {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    public Guestbook getEntry(int someid) {
        return em.find(Guestbook.class, someid);
    }
}
```

So this would produce a nullpointer exception when accessing the *em* in getEntry() because it is *null*.
My persistence.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="..." xmlns:xsi="..." xsi:schemaLocation="...">
    <persistence-unit name="guestbook" transaction-type="JTA">
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/mysqldatasource</jta-data-source>
        <class>model.Guestbook</class>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Thanks in advance, i'm looking forward for your suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've abstracted the `DAO` from `GuestService` just fine, but it seems that you forgot to make the `DAO` a `@Stateless` EJB and inject it in your `GuestService` using `@EJB` annotation.

```
@Stateless 
public class DAO {

   @PersistenceContext
   private EntityManager em;
   ...   
}

@Stateless
@Path("guestbook")
public class GuestService {

    @EJB
    private DAO dao;
    ...
}
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you very much, this really helped me and hinted at the mistake i made. I already had used those annotations the way you suggest. Now that i got this to work i tried to let the REST class implement an interface, but this gives me another error (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class). Can you hint at the source for this error? Thanks again!